# Storing luggage at Kunming Changshui Airport?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, luggage, luggage-storage, china-eastern

I am travelling to CCU India from LAX USA via China on China Eastern Airlines. My itinerary is as follows -

LAX => PVG => KMG => CCU

I have long layovers at PVG/KMG airports, but I was informed that my luggage will not go checked through to CCU. I will have collect it out at KMG. Where can I keep it at KMG so that I can go around sight-seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already travelled this route with a similar itinerary. The perks of travelling with China Eastern is that the prices are cheap and the food is pretty rad for the money you pay. Unfortunately, most of these flights can have a long layover time and sometimes (like it happened with me on this specific itinerary) you have to take the checked luggage out and re-check it in (even though all legs of the journey are with China Eastern). For these situations here are some tips -

- **TWOV policy** - TWOV (Transit With-Out Visa) policy for most nationals is the same, i.e. 24 hours from the point you set foot in China to the point you fly off. [Useful link for TWOV information](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-24hour.htm).
- **China Eastern STPC policy** - STPC stands for Stopover Paid by Carrier.
  If you are flying with China Eastern, and you have two connecting flights (both with CE) with a nightly lay-over in Shanghai, Kunming or Xi'an, China Eastern will provide a free hotel for you to spend the night. Requirements are that you have to book your tickets through their official website and you have to apply for the hotel at least 5 days before your departure date. [Useful link for STPC with CE](https://us.ceair.com/en/transit-hotel-application.html).
- On the particular itinerary mentioned in the question, there is a chance that the checked luggage needs to be collected at Kunming and re-check it. In case you want to keep your hands free and go around Kunming there are places where you can stash your luggage and collect it later. There are two places you can leave luggage for a small fee. The one that's most convenient for most travellers is in the arrivals hall, after exiting the place where you claim your checked luggage. Instead of proceeding outdoors to the taxi/bus area, turn hard right and look for the room near McDonalds and KFC. 50 Yuan is the maximum fee for most items, up to and including a large suitcase. Shorter times are less. These aren't lockers, they are large shelves. You need to show your passport to a clerk and have your bag X-rayed to be sure it doesn’t contain anything hazardous. They will also ask if you are checking valuables. You shouldn't do that. Sometimes they ask if there is a laptop computer, making me wonder if that might be forbidden. They give you a receipt and you pay at the time of pick up. Another similar room is on the third floor. Whichever one you use when you check your bag in is the one you go to claim it. No English available. But bilingual signs point to these rooms. If you need to ask someone, what you want is the **寄存行李房间。**(Show them that phrase on your phone.). [Useful link for things to do in Kunming](https://wikitravel.org/en/Kunming).